# Reading MySQL Data into a loop

Tags: c#, mysql

Currently, my method of pulling the information I need from the database and storing it as arrays works but it's rather tedious as I write it out individually.

Is there a way that I can read all the information from the desired column and increment it until it reaches the end? (I imagine a for loop)

So I connect to my database and I select the information I need:

```
            One = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[0]["Day"].ToString());
            Two = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[1]["Day"].ToString());
            Cost1 = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[0]["Cost"].ToString());
            Cost2 = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[1]["Cost"].ToString());
```

I then store it the data as an integer:

```
Total1 = Cost1 + Cost2;
Total2 = One + Two;
Overall = Total1 - Total2;
```

The result works but I feel as if it could be improved with a for loop taking a lot of the hard work out of it I attempted to use a for loop but it only took the last result out

```
for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int Day = Convert.ToInt32(dTable.Rows[i]["Day"]);
                lblTest.Text = Day.ToString();
            }
```

The last result would be 8000, altogether the combined result should be around 30,000 but it only takes the last result instead of adding each result up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last line of code overwrites `lblTest.Text` in each iteration, so you only get the last value.

You can fix the issue, and shorten this considerably, by using LINQ. You'll have to adjust this accordingly, for the types of your columns:

```
var rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();

var total1 = rows.Select(x => x.Field<decimal>("Cost")).Sum();
var total2 = rows.Select(x => x.Field<int>("Day")).Sum();
```

Comment: Appreciate your comment, but would it be possible to also post the code in C#? I have to work strictly in the code structure I've been told to work with unfortunately.

But this LINQ, is this more suitable for MySQL queries? If so, I'll remember to read up about it in the future.

Comment: After reading it back I understand it now, although if I remember rightly, I read in Step by Step Microsoft Visual C# 2013 - John Sharp that using 'var' is dirty code - did you use it primarily for the purposes of the example or do you use 'var' a lot in your work?

Comment: I see, thank you for showing me `var`'s practicality, it seems like a more attractive option rather than the latter now.